# what is the fastest way to get the height after changing the root of the tree?

Tags: java

I have a tree with n node, and m queries. For each query, they ask me to find the height of tree from a given node (assumes they choose that node as root).

we will have maximum `10^5` node, and `10^5` queries.

it's simple to get height from only one node as root. But for this problem, i don't see any efficient way to solve it.

I have to traverse the tree again and again for each query. It take too much time.

there must be some way that I can just traverse the tree only one from any node as root, and then calculate the height for each query.

So, is there any solution?

here is the problem :

you're given a tree with n vertices, and m queries. For each query, find the heigh of the tree when choosing vertex R as root

First line consists of N, i.e number of vertex. `1 <= n <= 10^5`

Next N-1 lines follow the type U V which denotes there is a path from U to V. `0 <= U, V <= n - 1`

Next line contain m, i.e number of query `1 <= m <= 10^5`

followed by m line, each line contain a vertex R chosen as root.

output the height for each query.

```
input
5
0 1
0 2
2 3
3 4
5
0
1
2
3
4
output
3
4
2
3
4
```

Comment: Please elaborate in the question that how new nodes are getting added and what kind of queries these are.

Comment: sorry, I forgot about that. I edited my question

Comment: I still don't understand the question.

Comment: sorry for my english. Can you understand the example ?? if i choose 0 as root, the height will be 3, choose 1 as root the height will be 4....and so on. The probIem is for each query like that I have to traverse the tree again to get the height from a given root. So it take a lot of time

Comment: @DucPham Please provide visual tree structure of your data and also label height of each node.

Comment: @KamilMahmood https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ6Hj.jpg  the label height at each node doesn't represent the height of that node, but it show the height of the tree if I choose that node as root

Comment: As you build the graph, in each node, save the height for each path leaving the node.  Then the answer to each query is just the max of those values.